# why does my awk code that should print word only on specific condition actually prints for all lines?

Tags: awk

I am trying to learn awk functionalities and as a simple exercise I try to print values in a file where if the first word is `PERMNO` then it should print the third word else it should just ignore.

the code I am using is

```
awk '{if ($1 = "PERMNO"){ print $3}}' ddoutput.txt
```

Right now this prints third word from every line. But I expect it to print only the third word when the first word of line is `PERMNO`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `PERMNO` really enclosed in single quotes or is it a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks for your answer. It works. I can apparently not mark it as correct answer for 10 mins.

Comment: With GNU awk for `--lint` running `awk --lint '{if ($1 = "PERMNO"){ print $3}}' file` outputs `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file FNR=1) warning: assignment used in conditional context` which is a big clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `$1 = "PERMNO"` you're assigning `PERMNO` to first field, which always evaluates to true. You should use the `==` operator like:

```
awk '{if($1=="PERMNO"){print $3}}' file
```

Or more awkish:

```
awk '$1=="PERMNO"{print $3}' file
```